# vim and system clipboard

Tags: vim, clipboard

I can cat a file, copy and paste text with the middle button or shift-insert.

How can I copy text in vim and paste it from the system clipboard?

Comment: sometimes I use `sed -n5,10p` to print lines 5-10 so I can more easily copy and paste without vim reacting to the mouse.

Comment: actually from inside vim the command looks like `:!sed -n 5,10p %`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. xclip is useful sometimes, thanks @sergiy-kolodyazhnyy. When I work on different machines I sometimes do not have control over which vim is installed but having the instructions for checking @muru 's answer is helpful, thanks @ashutosh-tripathy. I need to use the vim register commands more often to remember them when I need them. As I mentioned in the question above, if I want to do it quickly and the file is small the command inside vim looks like `:!cat %`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to have Vim with the `clipboard` and `xtermclipboard` features compiled in. In Ubuntu, these are only available with the vim GUI packages (`vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, `vim-athena`, etc.).

Once you install one of these, you can copy to (and paste from) the clipboard registers (`*` and `+`). From this very informative post on [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/205):

> For **X11**-based systems (ie. **Linux** and most other **UNIX**-like
>   systems) there are 2 clipboards, which are independent of each other:
>
> - PRIMARY - This is copy-on-select, and can be pasted with the middle mouse   button.
> - CLIPBOARD - This is copied with (usually) `^C`, and pasted with `^V` (It's   like MS Windows).
>
> ---
>
> Vim has 2 special registers corresponding to these clipboards:
>
> - `*` uses PRIMARY; mnemonic: **s**tar is **s**elect (for copy-on-**s**elect)
> - `+` uses CLIPBOARD; mnemonic: CTRL **+** C (for the common keybind)

To copy to a register, you precede the copy command (`y`) with `"` and the name of the register (`*`, for example). `"*y`, then middle-click to paste, or `"+y` and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score 5):

I had issue because my vim was not supporting **clipboard**:

```
vim --version | grep clip
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
```

I installed vim-gnome (which support clipboard) and then checked again:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
```

Now I am able to copy and paste using "+y and "+p respectively.

Comment: in ubuntu 20 this no longer works -had to install vim-gtk

Answer (score 4):

A quite interesting solution comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5130968/3701431) question. Install xclip, then pipe output of a command to xclip( `cat file | xclip -selection clipboard` for instance ), and then paste it anywhere, (if that's in terminal - use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>
). Now , turns out you can actually shorten that command to `xclip -sel clip`, which is not exactly apparent from reading man page or examples there.

Comment: Another way out is if you use screen or tmux, along with [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098). In any case, something needs to be installed.

Comment: What's the actual clipboard that is used in x server ? I didn't find anything in `/dev`, but text is still held somewhere, right ?

Comment: I always assumed it would be in memory. That seems like a nice question for [unix.se], though.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer, if you have compiled vim without `xclip` support, then do the following to copy content from vim to the system clipboard:

- Install `xclip` (`sudo apt install xclip`)
- Yank the required lines -  this will be stored in the `"0` register
- Then do `:call system('xclip -sel clipboard', @0)` to copy the contents to your clipboard.